# Spring security oauth2 and angular JS token in URL path?

Tags: angularjs, spring, security, oauth-2.0

I am creating a web app with angular-js in the front end and Spring in the back-end. For security I am making use of spring's oauth 2 token authentication. I have gotten everything to run fine by producing tokens. I am also able to inject them to my post calls via angular $http interceptors. However, I have one slight problem, once logged in I am unable to navigate to main page except with the token appearing in my URL **??!!!?!** How do I get rid of that ? right now it looks like this:

http://localhost:7001/app/console?access_token=7f7733bd-edbd-4de3-b192-a8059a89c461

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use browser's localstorage to save the token. Once saved, get rid of it from the url and navigate to the home page using any angular routing module. The http interceptors will read the token value from the localstorage when making requests to the server. There many angular module available to deal with the browser's localstorage.

Please let me know if you have any questions.

Thank you,
Soma.